# On Xcode (mac api) is there any file with a Sleep() function/command?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos-sierra

I coded a rpg on a school computer with a whole bunch of Sleep() functions in it and now when I come home I want to play it but I have a mac and Windows.h is not included in the api. Please help

Comment: Go standard compliant. This sucker won't care what OS you are using: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for . Just make sure you have 11 support enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use C++11 thread.

```
#include <thread>

std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
```